# How to dynamically name tags in html so to relate to them later?

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms

How should I name my select tags in template.html in order to be able pin point them, related to each separately, in the views.py whenever receiving the POST message?

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    {% for type in range( form.typesCount ) %}
    <div>
       <select name="???">
          {% for format in formats %}
             <option value="{{format}}"> {{ format }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
       </select>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loop.index`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-control-structures), which is an integer that returns the current iteration index inside Jinja `for` loops. For example:

```
{% for type in range( form.typesCount ) %}

   <select name="my-select-{{loop.index}}">
      ...
   </select>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Interesting, why loop.index starts from 1?

Comment: `loop.index0` starts from zero. See the documentation link above.